# Intersection of Infinite Collection of Sets (Real Analysis Ex: 1.1.7(b) Bartle)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was doing some revision using Bartle's Real Analysis book. I have the following question:

$\textbf{Q}$: For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $A_{n} = \{(n+1)k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Determine the set $\bigcap\{A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

I understand that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the elements of $A_{n}$ are multiples $(n+1)k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

$\textbf{Proof}$:
Assume that the $\bigcap A_{n} \neq \emptyset$. Then we must have $\bigcap A_{n} = \{xk : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, in other words the elements of the intersection $\bigcap A_{n}$ are multiples $xk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. It follows that by the above set definition we must have: $\bigcap A_{n} = \{xk : k \in \mathbb{N}\} = A_{x-1}$.

Now, let $y \in A_{x-1}$ such that $y = x(1)$, where $k = 1$. Then $y=x \notin A_{x-2} = \{(x-1), 2(x-1), 3(x-1), \ldots\}$. This provides us with a contradiction, since $A_{x-1} \subseteq A_{x-2}$ by the above argument.

Hence, $\bigcap A_{n} = \emptyset$ $\square$

I know that there's an easier and more succinct argument, then the one presented above, however, the above is my thought process. Could you please confirm if the above argument is valid! It'll go a long way to reinforce my understanding of sets.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if $x\in \cap A_n$ then $x$ can be divided by any natural number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\in \cap_{n\in \mathbb N} A_n$ then $x\ge n$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. But this would contradict Archimedean property of real numbers. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'd like to get validation as to if my proof is correct? As I'd like to confirm my understanding.

Comment: @ShahinNosratJogan What is $x$ in the second sentence of your proof?

Comment: It is some natural number such that the element of each set $A_{n}$ can be expressed as a multiple of $x$ for every natural number $k$. Take for example: $A_{1} \cap A_{2} = \{6k : k \in \mathbb{N} \} = A_{5}$.

Comment: But what guarantees that a $x$ exists such that $\cap_ {n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n= x\mathbb{ N}$? My argument show that if there was such a natural number $x$, it would be bigger than alll other natural numbers.

Comment: Does it not follow from the set definition $A_{n}$? Since take any element in $A_{n_{1}}$, then it's elements expressed as $(n_{1} + 1)k$. Now, assuming that $\bigcap A_{n} \neq \emptyset$, then elements in $\bigcap A_{n} \neq \emptyset$ should also be expressible as a multiple of some natural number.

Comment: No, you need to take an element $x \in A_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ . not some $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130468/discussion-between-shahin-nosrat-jogan-and-ashk).